# Are the contents of an app indexed by search functionality?

Tags: sharepoint-addin

If you create lists inside apps, does sharepoint also indexes that and show them on search results? Is there any extra step to be done for this to happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the app i SharePoint hosted, witch it has to be for you to be able to use SharePoint artifacts like lists, I guess the only thing you would need to do is to check that the App Catalog Site Collection is in scope for the search. (Though since Sharepoint will think of the App Catalog Site Collection as a subdomain there could really be some trouble here)

Not sure how the permissions on the Lists on an App is set per default though. This could be a problem if the users do not have direct permissions on the list (meaning that the list items would not be retreived by the search query).

Comment: Can you provide us with reference as where did you get this information from please?

Comment: On which part? If you mean about the crawling of the App Catalog Site Collection i really have no source, but it is just a normal site collection like any other i SharePoint really and hence will be indexed by search if it is in scope.

Comment: I thought it was a hidden site collection, and even if crawler crawls it doesn't mean it will crawls contents of applications too..

Comment: Not sure if it is hidden, but you can navigate to the Lists/ListName on your app web for the app instance to see the full content of the list (you will be redirected to AllItems.aspx) so it should be able to be indexed, right?

Comment: Not saying you are right or wrong, its just as I am not sure how it works. I also don't think we should just assume how things work, so was looking for confirmation through reference :)

Comment: Exactly, thats why I wrote it very broad and without sounding to sure ;) One of the problems is that the app host application will be treated as another domain (or at least subdomain) to Sharepoint, wonder how that will effect searchability

Comment: Let me refrase my answer a bit so I don't sound that secure! ;)

Answer (score 0):

They should be indexed by the search in Due course when they are added during the deploy process. It will depend on when the search indexing worker process runs (which happens in the background.

All of this differs from version to version, i.e 2010 and 2013, on premise, office 365 etc.